# Historical events calendar database

Tags: data-request, calendar

I'm looking for a database that contains information about events, specifically in NYC. Categories include these:

```
 "Athletic",
 "Business & Finance",
 "City Government Office",
 "Cultural",
 "Education",
 "Environment",
 "Featured",
 "Free",
 "General Events",
 "Health & Public Safety",
 "Hearings and Meetings",
 "Holidays",
 "Kids and Family ",
 "Parks & Recreation",
 "Street and Neighborhood",
 "Tours",
 "Volunteer"
```

I've found [this](https://developer.cityofnewyork.us/api/events-calendar) one but no matter my query it just returns data starting from the current date. I need historical data, like from 2015.

Comment: What do you need it for? Is fake data OK?

Answer (score 1):

I am on the search for similar data. This is what I could find on the NYC Open Data Platform, but apparently it only lists the events for the next month and it seems there is no way to query historical data:

https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/NYC-Permitted-Event-Information/tvpp-9vvx

It'd be great if others could point us towards alternative sources!

Thanks!